# Move 2d Array to Spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I take a 2d Array in google script and push the whole thing to a range in a spreadsheet?

Here is what I have:

Assume that array is created and filled and has 6000+ rows and 4 columns.

The following code gives me an incorrect range error.

> Incorrect range width was 0 but should be 4 (line 56, file "Code"):

`formatted.getRange(1,1,targetArray.length,targetArray[0].length).setValues(targetArray);`

The following code functions but times out because the data set is too large:

```
for(var i=0; i<formattedSheetLength; i++)
    formatted.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([targetArray[i]]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit Notes: Due to an OP comment, the original code was changed.

## Short answer

Try

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Create a jagged array for demonstration purposes 
  var targetArray = [
    [1,2],
    [1],
    [1,2,3],
    [1]
  ];

  /**
   * These two loops are safe because they don't make calls to 
   * the SpreadsheetApp service.
   */

  var height = targetArray.length;
  //Check the max width.
  var width = 0; 
  for(var i = 0; i < height; i++){
    width = Math.max(width,targetArray[i].length);
  }
  //Add the required empty values to convert the jagged array to a 2D array
  var temp;
  for(var i = 0; i < height; i++){
    temp = targetArray[i].length;
    for(var j = 0; j < width - temp; j++){
      targetArray[i].push('');
    }
  }
  /**
   * Send values to the spreadsheet in a single call
   */
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,height,width).setValues(targetArray);
}
```

## Explanation

According to the error message, `targetArray[0].length` is returning `0`. We could assume that `targetArray` is a jagged array instead of a 2D array. In order to avoid the use of a hardcoded width, the above code as an example of how to convert a jagged array into a 2D array.

The code has two loops that are safe to use because they doesn't call a Google Apps Script service.

Comment: I have tried this for testing purposes and it did not make a difference.  I don't usually like to hard code values like the 4 as that value might change in the data structure.  The targetArray[0].length will make it so that if the length of the inner arrays changes the program can handle it.

Comment: @SergeInsas: I'm sorry, I accidentally saved my edit before I finished.

Comment: no worries, I just saw it incidentally and though you had been simply distracted by "something" ;) , so, since I was there I did it !

Comment: @CharlieGorrill: I changed my answer.

Comment: Beautiful!  This worked great.  I did not account for the possibility of a jagged array.  I assumed that it would be consistent width due to the data source.