# Array to populate multiple columns on sheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Range D2:D20 I have text strings that i am searching for in my emails.  The number of threads in the resulting email is displayed in column E.

**EDIT**
I am attempting to create an array that will use `setvalues` for range H2:?20 (final column is variable).  Column H will be the value of variable `finding` and column I will show the first email message `str`.  Column J will be the second message, K the third, etc.

I think to do this I need a 2D array which will be

```
[[[finding],[str],[str],[str]],[[finding],[str]],[[finding],[str],[str],[str],...]]
```

I may be wrong with this assumption though.

I have been converting the email message `str` to an array with `Strarr`.
I have then been adding this (I think) to `ColHarr`.

I am getting the error:
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 1.
at findemail2(del:52:43)

I am sure I am making a mess of the array though.  I'm not even sure if a 2D array is what I require.
Can anyone advise or tell me where I am going wrong?

```
function findemail() {
// For each row, show the messages for the email address (across columns)
  var wkbk = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht = wkbk.getActiveSheet();
  var allemails = sht.getRange('D2:D20'); //'+sht.getLastRow());
  var emailVal = allemails.getValues();
  var str = "";
  var ColEarr = [];
  var ColHarr = [[]];
  var Strarr = [];
  var strstr = "";
  
  for (var b = 0; b < emailVal.length; b++) {      // for each email in list, search
    var finding = emailVal[b];
    var eml = GmailApp.search('"'+finding+'"');
    
    for (var n = 0; n < eml.length; n++) {         // for each thread found
      var thds  = eml[n];
      var AllMsgs = thds.getMessages();
  
      for (var m = 0; m < AllMsgs.length; m++) {   // for each message, get text
        var msg  = AllMsgs[m];
        var body = msg.getPlainBody();
        var hdr = msg.getDate() + "/n" + msg.getTo() + ' ##CC ' + msg.getCc() + ' ##BCC ' + msg.getBcc() + ' ##From ' + msg.getFrom() + ' ##Subject ' + msg.getSubject();
        
        str = hdr + "/n" + body;
        if (str !== "") {
          var found = str.includes(finding);       // check if email found in string
        }
        Strarr = finding;
        ColHarr.push(Strarr);
        if (found) {
          if (str.length < 50000) {
            Strarr = ([str]);
            ColHarr = ColHarr.concat([Strarr]);       // message to display
          } else {
            Strarr = ([str.slice(0,49999)]);
            ColHarr = ColHarr.concat([Strarr]);       // restrict message size if over 50k characters
          }
        } else {
          Strarr = ([found]);
          ColHarr = ColHarr.concat([Strarr]);         // if no match in message, show false
        }
      }
    }
    ColEarr.push([eml.length]);
    Logger.log(b);
    str = "";
  }
// setvalues E + H...
  sht.getRange('E2:E'+(ColEarr.length+1)).setValues(ColEarr);
  sht.getRange('H2:H'+(ColHarr.length+1)).setValues(ColHarr);
}
```

Comment: Hey, what exactly do you mean by "I am struggling with getting the search term to display in column H with I, J"? What will these columns contain? Also, why are you using a 2D array? Would you mind providing more explanations about what is it that you want to achieve? @GlibGibon

Comment: Sorry about that.  I shouldn't stay up until 6 then try to explain things.  Hopefully this is a little clearer.  @ale13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a 2D array (i think), but I was doing it wrong.
`var ColHarr = [[]];` should be a 1D array `var ColHarr = [];`

At the start of the For loops I should have added the search value to the `Strarr` as I only need it once.

```
var eml = GmailApp.search('"'+finding+'"');
Strarr.push(finding);
```

And of course I should not have been assigning the array elements with `=`, but pushing them.

```
    if (found) {
      if (str.length < 50000) {                // message to display
        Strarr.push([str]);
      } else {
        Strarr.push([str.slice(0,49999)]);     // restrict message size if over 50k characters
      }
    } else {
      Strarr.push([found]);                    // if no match in message, show false
    }
```

Pushing `Strarr` to `ColHarr` (creating a 2D array) should not have been done until after all the messages for all the threads of a search had been processed.  I can then reset `Strarr` for the next search term.

```
ColHarr.push(Strarr);
Strarr = [];  //.length = 0;
```

Setting values for `ColEarr` worked fine. For `ColHarr`, I had to find the length of the largest array for setting the Range but also to change `ColHarr` from a jagged array to 2D.
Rubén had a [very helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112429/move-2d-array-to-spreadsheet/40142689#40142689) on how to do that.  Then I could use setValues to show the messages.

```
  //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
  sht.getRange(2, 8, emailVal.length, width).setValues(ColHarr);
```

All I need to do now is tidy up the cell heights and widths; then get some sleep.